# How can I bulk insert records with UUID primary keys using insert_all in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, bulkinsert, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a controller action which, upon creation of a parent object, generates and saves a batch of M-M associations. The database is Postgres and all relevant tables in the application use UUIDs.

When I use `insert_all!` on this batch of records the insert fails with `ArgumentError (No unique index found for id)`. I assume this is because I'm not providing IDs for the records I'm trying to insert, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to be able to.

From my understanding, `gen_random_uuid()` is a Postgres function, not a Rails one. I understand that `insert_all!` and similar functions skip Rails callbacks but `gen_random_uuid()` is set as the default value for these records at the *Postgres* level, so why is this not being respected? Surely I don't have to manually provide UUIDs for each record?

If I *do* have to manually provide the UUIDs, how do I? Is there a corresponding function in Rails which generates the same type of UUID? I've come across `SecureRandom.uuid` but the UUIDs generated by this function do not appear to be the same as the ones generated by Postgres.

All examples I can find in the docs, on this website and in blogs use basic IDs, so haven't been helpful. I would also like to avoid adding more gems if possible - this smells like something that should be built into Rails.

Not sure if this is relevent but the database is tenanted, so tables use `tenant_id` and `id` composite primary keys.

In summary my question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to tell `insert_all!`, ActiveRecord or Postgres to respect the `gen_random_uuid()` default, so that the UUIDs can be generated automatically by the database (as they are in all other record creation scenarios)?
2. If not, how can I generate suitable UUIDs in Rails to assign to the records?

Thank you in advance.

---

#### Notes

Migration:

```rb
create_table :foo, primary_key: [:tenant_id, :id] do |t|
  t.uuid :id, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
  t.references :tenant, null: false, index: false
  t.references :foo, null: false, type: :uuid
  t.references :bar, null: false, type: :uuid
  t.timestamps

  t.index :id, unique: true
end
```

`structure.sql` (autogenerated by Rails upon migration):

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.foo (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    tenant_id bigint NOT NULL,
    foo_id uuid NOT NULL,
    bar_id uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.assignments
    ADD CONSTRAINT assignments_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, id);

CREATE INDEX index_assignments_on_foo_id ON public.assignments USING btree (foo_id);

CREATE INDEX index_assignments_on_bar_id ON public.assignments USING btree (bar_id);

CREATE INDEX index_assignments_on_id ON public.assignments USING btree (id);
```

Controller:

```rb
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
  authorize(@foo)

  if @foo.save
    scope = { 
      # Attribute values to determine scope
    }
    timestamp = Time.zone.now
    assignments = Bar.where(scope).pluck(:id).map do |bid|
        {
          foo_id: @foo.id,
          bar_id: bid,
          created_at: timestamp,
          updated_at: timestamp,
        }
    end


    Assignment.insert_all!(assignments)
    render turbo_stream: [turbo_stream_foos, flash_notification(:success, "Successfully created foo")]
  else
    render turbo_stream: [turbo_stream_foo_new_form, flash_notification(:error, "Error creating foo")]
  end
end
```

Full trace:

```
No unique index found for id:
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/insert_all.rb:124:in `find_unique_index_for'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/insert_all.rb:31:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:213:in `new'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:213:in `insert_all!'
  /home/careportal/app/controllers/foos_controller.rb:37:in `create'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:53:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'
  /home/careportal/app/controllers/concerns/core/use_time_zone.rb:11:in `use_time_zone'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/active_decorator-1.4.0/lib/active_decorator/view_context.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Filter>'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/active_decorator-1.4.0/lib/active_decorator/view_context.rb:25:in `run_with'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/active_decorator-1.4.0/lib/active_decorator/view_context.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Filter>'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actiontext-7.0.4/lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actiontext-7.0.4/lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-7.0.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:696:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/better_errors-2.9.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:62:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:19:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:61:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:26:in `collect_events'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:60:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-mini-profiler-3.0.0/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:393:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-cors-1.1.1/lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Ruby version: 3.1.2

Rails version: 7.0.3

Comment: ArgumentError (No unique index found for id) -- tells you exactly what the issue is.  You need a unique index on the id column for the table.

Comment: @dbugger I already have a unique index on the ID (at least I think that's what `t.index :id, unique: true` in the migration does) and Google only gives three results when I search for the error message. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can generate UUIDs using `SecureRandom.uuid` but I would not recommend this. Can you please post code that reproduces this issue? And maybe a stack trace as what you have provided is likely insufficient for us to determine what is actually causing the error.  Sidenote: your "Schema Fragment" does not show `id` is a PRIMARY KEY (not really the issue here.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for clarifying about `SecureRandom.uuid`. I've added more code, schema and the full stack trace to the question.

Comment: @dbugger it turns out you were right! I had edited the migration but somehow not reset the database state back far enough for the new unique index to be picked up when I reran the migrations. Only noticed when I set my dev env up on a new environment and the `structure.sql` file updated. If you're willing to write up an answer response I'll mark it as accepted.